# Configure a JTree like a JFileChooser?

Tags: java, swing, jtree, jfilechooser

I am new to using JTrees in Java. I am kind of in doubt as to how to configure it the way I want. I've been looking around for answers, but either I am not searching right, or maybe it's not possible without extensive coding?

1. I want to use a JTree to show all files on the computer and update whenever a file is changed/added/created/deleted etc. (Does JTree keep track of this itself?)
2. Place a check box next to all files that have a Cpp extension.
3. Some kind of method to get all the files that have had their box checked and pass it to parser I've made.

How would I go about this exactly? I can't really seem to find an easy way to configure the JTree as I please, unless I am completely missing something?

Comment: Have a look over the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui) for tips.

Comment: *"1) ..(Does JTree keep track of this itself?)"* No.  Look to the [file watch service](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) for changes and refresh the model of the tree. 2) Use a [tree cell renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeCellRenderer.html) 3) *"Some kind of method to get all the files that have had their box checked"* By the logic of point (2) that would be the `.cpp` files, right?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I will have a look at those. And to the last question: Yes.

Comment: @Vipar: See also this [`Outline`](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692) view.